# how to make predictionio/flatspec create HTML output if I run the tests in sbt?

Tags: html, scala, unit-testing, sbt, predictionio

please help me with this issue:
I have unit test in predictionio and want to create HTML output for that

The code is similar to this
https://github.com/PredictionIO/template-scala-parallel-similarproduct/blob/develop/src/test/scala/CooccurenceAlgorithmTest.scala

how to make predictionio create HTML output if I run the tests in sbt?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, in build.sbt:

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    ...
    "org.scalatest"    %% "scalatest"     % "2.2.1" % "test",
    "org.pegdown"      % "pegdown"        % "1.0.2" % "test"
)

testOptions in Test += Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.ScalaTest, "-h", "target/report")